# Blender Freestyle - some edges are partially missing even after marking for Freestyle edges

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

I am trying to render some simple geometric form using freestyle in Blender. But  parts of some edges are missing - even though I have marked freestyle edges. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: discontinuous edges]

[image: edge settings]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, all marked edges show up fine.

Comment: This might be a good one to share your file on at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Here is the .blend file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6308" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6308/)

By the way, I am using Blender 2.8 Beta downloaded today on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to stem from the scale of the object. While you've set the unit scale down, it's still large in Blender units. I suggest setting the unit scale back to one and scale the object to the size in millimeter that you were intending. This results in correct freestyle edges.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your solution seem to work. 
But it messes up the scaling when you import any other object. The freestyle line issue is seems to be resolved but it's started a new confusion regarding my understanding of the  the unit settings in Blender 2.80...
By the way, how did you change the scale without changing the object size?
When I change the scale I have to scale the object down (by 1000th) also and re-frame the shot by moving the camera close. Did you do that or is there a better way?

Comment: @saicode you can adjust the scale in most importers, you just have to know in what dimensions it's stored and what dimensions your scene has. I did scale the object. First I've set the unit size to 1 so that it maps exactly to one Blender unit. Then I've adjusted the object size to the one it's supposed to in mm. The camera position needs to be adjusted, but the change is also relative to the scaling factor.

Comment: @saicode I'm not sure if freestyle has a problem with unit scale not being 1, but generally I'd keep it at that value unless you really need the increased precision for small real world scale of object in mm or below.

Comment: @saicode I just tested with a unit scale of 0.01 and adjusted scales, it works as well. It could be that the large distance ranges in Blender units in your scene result in a precision loss in the depth map which causes these artefacts in freestyle rendering.

Comment: thanks again! when you are using metric system and want to use mm as the unit, I thought the rule was to make the scale factor 0.001 (basically 1meter/1000 = 1mm) - with this settings importing files from other programs (esp. CAD) is easy - it comes in the right scale and you don't have to apply anything at all. And it works flawlessly with every kind rendering - this is the first time I am am coming across any problem due to scaling factor.

Comment: @saicode just to be clear the unit scale is NOT for conversion within metric, but how metric units are converted to Blender units. So if you import .dxf you will need to scroll down in the setting. There is an option Unit Scale (unfortunate naming, it's not the same as the unit settings' unit scale) that says on the tool tip "Coordinates are assumed to be in meters.". So the addon apparently can't figure the scale out on it's own, which means you need to set this to the appropriate value for your import.

Comment: but if the scale factor is set to 0.001 then the OBJ files exported from the CAD programs comes to blender in the correct scale without any issue. I don't have change anything in the import settings. 

Until 2.79b one had to change the scale to 0.001 if they wanted to enter a value in any field and wanted it to be recognized as mm in blender and not meter or blender unit. 

I have to take a re-look into it - and if I don't find an answer I may post a fresh question here again.

Comment: @saicode yes it works, but with the consequence that now 1m = 0.001 BU. The question is whether or not that is your intention, because of the consequences this has. You can simply set the scale in the import setting and keep the unit scale for the scene at 1 (unless numerical precision is key because your modelling at a tiny scale). Entering values in km/m/cm/mm e.g. for object size is always possible. The unit scale only makes a difference in how many blender units this occupies. If you have a preference in how lengths are displayed you can change that in the dropdown in the units panel.

Comment: I never thought from that perspective, perhaps because I use mm for most of my work. And 1mm=0.001 BU is correct as BU is metric (1M=1BU) from Blender 2.80. Looks like Blender needs another round of work for its unit system.